# Root site collection or not

Tags: site, web-application

I just installed SharePoint on our server and now we will start to configure our sites. I have a organizational question about the localization of the sites.

When we are configuring a new Webapplication and we need to determine a template to use on it, we need to choose a path:

What is the difference between:

- to use a root super(parent) site and have child sites on it with other templates.
- DO NOT use a root(parent) site and just have `"/" + "sites"` + our individual sites.

Can anyone guide us and tell us when to choose the first option and when to choose the second one?

Answer (score 2):

It is depend upon your requirement( storage, SharePoint usage, #of users, customization, #department, Security etc).

Either you go with root level Site collection with many sub sites or use a managed path site collection with many subsites, things will be same except the URL.
`http://webapplication.com` to `http://webapplication.com./sites/sitename.`

One thing, You have to have the root level site collection for smooth operations of SharePoint, if you dont have root level site collection then many features which relies on the _layouts will fail and cause the issue.

Another thing, you can create multiple site collections on managed path i.e /sites/a, sites/b etc.

Comment: I can have only one site collection with a PUBLISHING PORTAL template e after, I can create other SUBSITES with another template like My Site Host?

Comment: Oh hu...you want to create the mysite as a subsite? Mysites should be in own Web application and also as a site collection not subsite.

Answer (score 0):

There are many considerations to be done.
Anyway, I will  just give a quick and dirt answer to point at some issues.

- The first option is easier to manage as you will have a single site collection with many subsites in it. 
  This can be an option if the site is not too big as for example there is a
  200 GB supported limit for content db and a site collection can only have 
  one content db.
- With the second option you will have one root site collections and many site collections. You don't have the limits above, but it is not so easy to manage as for example subsites might inherits Group and security from their parent site. This does not happen if you opt for many site collections under sites

As I wrote, this is just quick and dirty and certainly not exhaustive as there are other options and issues to consider...

Comment: So anyway I will have always a PARENT SITE (in the root?) or I can create just http:// blablablawebapplication / SITES / sites here

Comment: yes you will always have a root as they are in the same web application. Anyway, you might also add blablablawebapplication / SITES / sites to it but they would be in a different site collection

Comment: so I can have only one site collection with a PUBLISHING PORTAL template e after, I can create other SUBSITES with another template like My Site Host?

Comment: You can have more site collections whatever of the 2 patterns you choose.  So you can have a site collection that  follow the first pattern and other site collections that follow your second pattern (all in one webapplcation). Anyway, subsites that stay under one site collection can only inherit from their parent site or site collection.